# Google Apps Script Popup to maintain widgets when re-opened

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a script using Google Apps Script with UiApp and I need to maintain the widgets in a popup after reopen it.

e.g. Open a popup, create some listboxes, close the popup and on reopen the same listboxes should be there.

Any sugestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you close and reopen a UI you get a new instance of it so that the widgets will have forgotten everything they knew ;-)

You'll have to take care of it yourself and store every data somewhere so that you can restore the previous state when the new Ui shows up.

The place to store and the way to do it are your choice and depend mainly on the context in which you use that Ui.

Comment: In my case the widgets are "filters".

Do you advise me to store them in hidden fields?

Comment: hidden fields won't survive neither... they belong to the Ui and therefor only exist in the scope of this Ui instance. I was thinking of scriptdB or properties...

Comment: Yes, but I can add the hidden fields to the widget on the background.

Comment: what do you mean by "on the background" ?

Comment: The popup is not my main widget. I've widgets behind it. I can add the hidden fields there, right?

Comment: Right!  It wasn't obvious from your question in which context you were... :-). Tags are also a good place to hide things ...

Comment: Yes, I've used them in a few situations :)